# the usage of 'never done' in colloquial English

Tags: ellipsis, conversational-deletion

Dialogues:

Have you been to Paris?

No, never been.

Have you heard John's ex-wife?

No, never heard.

Can I shorten the answers as above in colloquial English?

Comment: "Colloquial English" varies from place to place, and varies based on the age and class of the speakers.  Phrases like "No, never been" might be common among some groups, and rare among others.  Which location and speakers are you asking about?

Answer (score 4):

As Jasper says, 'colloquial English' represents a very wide range of dialects—not to mention a wide range of utterances, which frequently include dysfluencies and slips of the tongue. Consequently, you ***might*** hear almost anything.

But let's assume that there's something we could call 'standard colloquial English', and we're talking about that.

Your sentences involve two very different sorts of ellipsis of the 'full sentences' we theoretically assume underlie them.

- *Conversational deletion* takes place at the beginning of a sentence. It permits the speaker to omit anything which can be "recovered" from the context and begin the utterance with the first piece of new information.

  > **A:** <s>Have you</s> ever been to London or Paris?
  >   **B:** <s>I have</s> Been to London, <s>I have</s> never been to Paris.
- *Auxiliary stranding* takes place at the end of a clause. It permits the speaker to reduce an entire VP (a verb plus its complements) to the single auxiliary verb which heads the VP, provided the rest of the VP can be recovered from the context.

  > **A:** Have you been to Paris?
  >   **B:** I have <s>been to Paris</s>.

  Note that exactly the same "Coding" of a VP in its auxiliary occurs with tag questions:

  > You've been to Paris, **have**n't you?

  Only **auxiliary** verbs have the Code property which licenses this sort of reduction; it doesn't work with lexical verbs, so this isn't permitted:

  > **A:**: Have you ever heard John's ex-wife sing?
  >   **B:**: <sup>∗</sup> Never heard ... *this is expressed as*
  >   **B:**: <sup>ok</sup>Never have

  But this can get tricky when we're dealing with dialect or idiomatic forms in which the auxiliary status of a verb is ambiguous. For instance, your *never been* example is made possible by two factors: a) Even when it acts as a 'lexical' verb, *BE* is usually treated as an auxiliary, and b) In most US colloquial speech an unstressed auxiliary *have* can be omitted, so the bare participle carries the entire verbal burden. Similarly, the idiom *have got* = 'have' is employed very differently in the US and the UK. British speakers (mostly) apprehend the construction as a perfect, so it's usually Coded with *have*:

  > **A:** Got a ticket?
  >   **B:** I have.

  But for most US speakers, the *have* in *have got* is dispensed with or replaced with a *do have* construction in non-assertive contexts, so the same dialogue with B as an American will employ *do* as its Code auxiliary:

  > **A:** Got a ticket?
  >   **B:** I do.

Answer (score 2):

> Have you been to Paris?
>
> No, never been.

This is fine.  A native speaker would use this.

> Have you heard John's ex-wife?
>
> No, never heard.

This is not how most people would reply.  Most would reply with:

> No, never heard her.

Comment: There is no **of** in the second question ("*Have you heard John's ex-wife?*").  Supposedly it's about John's ex-wife voice (speaking or singing), not about her *person*.

Comment: @VictorBazarov good catch.  Fixed